# (GLib) How to create and emit GSignals?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glib

I am trying to create a wm based on XCB.I use GApplication for my base object.I try to create a new GSignal and emit it based on certain xcb events.The program compiles fine, but when I run it and the event happens I get an error :
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 09:45:01.395: ../glib/gobject/gsignal.c:3492: signal name 'pointer-motion' is invalid for instance '0x5597bbb9e890' of type 'GApplication'.
Here is how I create the signal:

```
  g_signal_new ("pointer-motion",
                G_TYPE_FROM_CLASS (class),
                G_SIGNAL_DETAILED |
                G_SIGNAL_ACTION |
                G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,
                0,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                G_TYPE_NONE,
                1,
                G_TYPE_POINTER);
```

Here is how I emit it:

```
g_signal_emit_by_name (fairy,
                       "pointer-motion",
                       motion_notify_event);
```

And this is the full source:
https://pastebin.com/TMtQFwAb.
Can somebody point me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal code looks fine. The issue that the error message *"signal is invalid for instance of type GApplication"* is hinting at is that you never actually instantiate your object:

```
fairy_wm_new (const gchar *id, GApplicationFlags flags)
{
  return g_object_new (G_TYPE_APPLICATION,"application-id",id,"flags",flags,NULL);
}
```

This returns a pointer to a GApplication, not a FairyWM. Use `FAIRY_TYPE_WM` instead.

Comment: I wonder how I missed . It doesn't trow the error anymore . I am still confused why the compiler didn't trow an incompatible pointer type error. Since the fairy_wm_new function returns a non FairyWM pointer. (Maybe becouse GApplication is the parent type of FairyWM)